# Firebase cloud functions not waiting for forEach to complete before jumping to the next then

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Been trying to copy subcollections of a collection into another collection. The code below is aimed at that, but jumps from the first then and logs out "Done" without logging out anything before.

So the question is what is not correct here?

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
    let db = admin.firestore();

    try {
      await db.collection("users").get().then((query) => {
          return query.forEach(async (doc) => {
            console.log("Here");                  //This doesn't print
            const polCollection = await db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).collection("xyz").get();
          
            if (polCollection.docs.length > 0) {  //This checks if any subcollections
             
              for (const x of polCollection.docs) { //This copies them into a doc in the copy collection
                db.collection("CopyUsers")
                  .doc(doc.id)
                  .set({ x : x.data() }, { merge: true });
              }
            }
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Done");  //This is the only thing that prints in the console
          
            res.end();
         
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("e", e);
          
            res.end();
         
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
     
        res.end();
    
    }
});
```

After the suggestion below, it now looks as follows:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  const promises = [];


    let count = 0;
    let size = 0;

    return await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("testUsers")
      .get()
      .then((query) => {

        console.log("query length:", query.size); //prints x of users
        size = query.size;

        query.forEach(async (doc) => {
          const promise = async () => {
            console.log("Here", doc.id); //This doesn't print
            await admin
              .firestore()
              .collection("testUsers")
              .doc(doc.id)
              .collection("xyz")
              .get()
              .then(async (polCollection) => {
                if (polCollection.docs.length > 0) {
                  for (const x of polCollection.docs) {
                    
                    return await admin
                      .firestore()
                      .collection("testBackUpUsers")
                      .doc(doc.id)
                      .set(
                        { xyz: x.data()  },
                        { merge: true }
                      );
                  }
                } else {
                  return;
                }
              })
              .catch((e) => console.log("error from then after get xyz", e));
          };
          count++;
          return promises.push(promise);
        });
        return promises;
      })
      .then(async (promises) => {
        if (size <= count) {
          console.log("running return Promise.all(promises)", promises.length); //prints number of promises = users

          return Promise.all(promises);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log("err from the last catch", e));

});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `forEach` iterator does not support `async/await`. Even if you write an await inside it will just go trough it without waiting on the execution.

I would recommend to use `Promise.all`. That would also execute the code in parallel and would finish faster.

If you would only change data you could also use a `batch` change but in your example you first get the data and then change it.

Here is an example how you could write your code:

```js
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let db = admin.firestore();
  const promises = [];

  try {
    const query = await db.collection("users").get();

    query.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log("doc", doc);
      const promise = async () => {
        console.log("Here", doc.id); //This doesn't print
        const polCollection = await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(doc.id)
          .collection("xyz")
          .get();

        if (polCollection.docs.length > 0) {
          //This checks if any subcollections

          for (const x of polCollection.docs) {
            //This copies them into a doc in the copy collection
            await db
              .collection("CopyUsers")
              .doc(doc.id)
              .set({ x: x.data() }, { merge: true });
          }
        }
      };

      promises.push(promise);
    });

    console.log("promises", promises);

    await Promise.all(promises);

    console.log("Done");
    res.end();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);

    res.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, still not executing. I've got a sizeable collection of about 5k entries, maybe that's throttling the function?

Comment: No errors, it prints "Done", but doesn't print "Here"... Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you pls update your code with the additional logs. I updated the code in the answer. Maybe your `users` collection is emoty. Just to make sure we have there something.

Comment: Added the extra logs, users is definitely not empty and  console.log('doc',doc) printed out a ton of them, though not all and it didn't print "Here". 
```
12:31:47.447 pm
csvCopyColls
Function execution took 3457 ms, finished with status code: 200
12:31:47.441 pm
csvCopyColls
Done
12:31:47.363 pm
csvCopyColls
[AsyncFunction],

12:31:47.355 pm
csvCopyColls
doc x a few hundred logs
```

Comment: So    promises.push(async () => {
        console.log("Here", doc.id); //This doesn't print 
never gets executed for some reason...

Comment: Can you pls try the code from the updated answers.

Comment: The logs above are from the updated version. The issue is that the promises are never executed for some reason.

Comment: Can you copy the exact code you use into your answer. The latest one. If you miss just a small part of the answer it won't work as expected. I would like to check that.

Comment: Sure, have a look at the code in the updated question. I've tried different iterations, yours and this current one chaining the steps all into a then sequence. The same issue persists that the promises in the array are not executed and "Here" never logs, despite them being added to the array and promises.length logs the correct number of docs.

Comment: Do your run `await Promise.all(promises);` with the `await` before it?

Comment: Yes, tried both with and without, no difference, unfortunately

Comment: What's quite confusing is why "Here" is never printed meaning the promise is never attempted to run

Comment: Is the code in your question your current code? Because that one would not work as expected. That is the reason I ask. If it's not could you pls update the question with your latest code. If it is I will update my answer with the mofifications you need to do.

Comment: @Vlad you need to copy exactly the code I wrote in the answer. The solution you show in your question updated will not work as expected! The reason is that you mix my code with yours and a `await ascnCallFunction().then(()=>{})` will not work as you expect it. So pls copy exactly the code from me and try it out.

Comment: Your code doesn't run either. There is a common error in both of our code examples that prevents them from running. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: What error do you get when runing my code?

Comment: The functions in the promises just don't run. Try it for yourself and you'll see console.log("Here", doc.id); //This doesn't print

Comment: pls update in you question how your current code looks like